# dc.js: cannot scroll past chart even after setting mouseZoomable to false

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

**Background**

I have created a chart and implemented a click-to-zoom/mouseout-to-reset-zoom feature as follows.

```
chart.on('pretransition', (c) => {
  // click to enable zooming
  c.select('svg').on('click.enablemousezoomable', () => {
    c.focus();
    c.mouseZoomable(true).render();
  });

chart.on('postRedraw', (c) => {
  // mouseleave to disable zooming
  c.select('svg').on('mouseleave.disablemousezoomable', () => {
    c.focus();
    c.mouseZoomable(false).render();
  });
});
```

**Problem**

While the feature works as intended, the problem is that after redrawing, page scrolling is impossible if the cursor remains on the chart.

The cursor needs to be moved off of the chart in order to get page scrolling to work.

**Question**

What might be causing this problem and what is the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, does this issue help? https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/991

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding the line and having it in addition to and instead of setting `mouseZoomable(false)`, but it did not disable mouse zooming and seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a block from the dc.js stock example, which uses `mouseZoomable` in the **Monthly Index Abs Move & Volume/500,000 Chart**, and [applied your changes](https://bl.ocks.org/gordonwoodhull/raw/0ea663248a2dd5b0cc86feb237c693dd).

Indeed, it disables zoom but it still leaves the wheel disabled after `mouseZoomable` has been disabled.

As [dc.js#991](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/991) discusses, the way dc.js removes zoom is incorrect. According to [the d3-zoom documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/v1.8.3/README.md#zoom), this should be correct:

```
moveChart._nullZoom = function(sel) {
    sel.on('.zoom', null);
};
```

Indeed, I tried it in [this fork of the block](https://bl.ocks.org/gordonwoodhull/raw/357982c367d0964c735cbb5af60aaca5/), and it seems to work much better. I think it's the correct fix for the linked issue, too.

There are some artifacts due to the redraws for adding and removing zoom, but I think they are out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! I have tried your fix, and it seems to work. I have accepted your answer.